# MS DOS replace : to - in string of bat file

Tags: batch-file, dos

There are a simple question to do:

```
set str=800:801
```

i need that ":" symbol to be replaced to "-"

Comment: i tried some replaces like set str = %str:":"="-"% but with no results.. sorry, i have really low experience with writing such things, so i need some help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :
SET str=%str::=-%

Comment: omg, thanks. I tried to write it in command line, and got no results, but in bat file its working ok. Thank you.

Comment: on the command line you can use ^ prefix to escape special characters